# Prevent files from being dropped onto browser

Tags: javascript

In short, if I drag any random file from my desktop onto my browser, the browser (Chrome and FF at the very least) will attempt to load that file as the browser's new location.  Is there a good way to turn that off?

The background is that I have drag and drop enabled on the module I'm working.  Users can drag files onto a designated dropzone, and the file is uploaded.  This works wonderfully.  The problem is that if the user misses, then the stupid feature described above takes over and the user finds themselves looking at the image (or whatever) displayed in browser, rather than the file being uploaded by my site.

I tried something naive like this

```
$(document).on('drop', function(){
    alert('x ');
});
```

but sadly this event is **only** triggered when the user drops over my valid dropzone, which of course won't work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you'd have to make the entire window a drop zone, but ignore it unless it happened to be right on your actual desired drop zone. otherwise it's just default browser behavior, which isn't something you'd want to mess with.

Comment: @MarcB - I feared as much.  Thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the naive approach mentioned in the question was surprisingly close.  Adding the dragover event is all it needs, apparently.

```
$(document).on('drop dragover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: If I put this in the (document).ready event, it prevents dropping things on to anywhere including the area i've made droppable.  How do you prevent dropping everywhere except the drop zones?